# Positioning form and text widges using XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on a project in work and there are two questions I am not sure about which I would be grateful if anyone could be tell me if this is doable or not.

A) Would it be rather difficult to have an XML file which would contain data that would be used to dictate the location of objects on screen. Was thinking storing coordinates, then parsing the coordinates, and setting up the layout in Java using the information stored in the xml document. Do you reckon this would end up being way too complicated using this method?

Now I doubt this is possible, but just want to be sure.

B) Is it possible to store EditText, TextView and other widgets etc in an XML file and parse it using Java and then add it to your layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a) and b):

We do it like this as and it works fine :)

More specifically:

A) We use a FrameLayout and dynamically add the UI elements to it. Using margins it is easy to set the size and position

B) We have an activity which can display arbitrary forms that are specified in an XML file. building it up is a few hundred lines of code but it works fine.

---

Some code on how to set up a UI based on XML:

First of all I assume that you know how to parse an XML file and store the relevant information in an object. The View that contains all the UI elements from the XML file is called `frame` in the following example.

```
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(context);

    // assemble views
    // XmlElement is one element in the XML file
    // page and cntnr are of type XmlElement
    for (XmlElement cntnr : page.getChildren())
    {
        content.addView(getViewForContainer(cntnr, context));
    }
```

You can now use `frame` for `setContentView` or add it to another `ViewGroup`.
Missing is the method `getViewForContainer`:

```
private static View getViewForContainer(XmlElement cntnr,
        Activity context)
{
    Rect bounds = cntnr.getBounds();
    int w = bounds.right;
    int h = bounds.bottom;

    // here is your View
    View ret = new View(context);

    // do this for all kinds of container
    // type is an enum that defines what kind of UI element 
    // a XML element is.
    switch (cntnr.getType())
    {
        case IMAGE:
            ret = createImage(context, pageContainer);
            break;
        case VIDEO:
            ret = createVideo(context, pageContainer);
            break;
        case AUDIO:
            ret = createAudio(context, pageContainer, page);
            break;
        ...
        case TEXT_FIELD:
            ret = createTextField(context, pageContainer);
            break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

You do that for all kinds of UI elements. I'll just show the `createImage()` as example:

```
private static View createImage(Activity context,
        XmlElement page)
{
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(RessourceLoader
                .getFilesDirectory() + page.getFile()));

    setImageViewPosition(iv, page);
    return iv;
}
```

Here is the method for setting the position of a View. It works only for FrameLayouts and uses margins. Also it assumes that the `frame` uses the whole screen. If you do not want it to fill the whole screen then use some other windowWidth and -Height.

```
private static void setViewPosition(View view, Activity context,
    XmlElement page)
{
        final int windowWidth = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        final int windowHeight = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    Rect bounds = page.getBounds();
        int x = bounds.left;
    int y = bounds.top;
        int w = bounds.right;
        int h = bounds.bottom;

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(w != 0 ? w : android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, h != 0 ? h : android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(x, y, w != 0 ? windowWidth - w - x : 0, h != 0 ? windowHeight - h - y : 0);
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

As I said: A few hundred lines of code. Could also be done better using classes and factories etc ... but you get the idea on how it works :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on point B please, I am not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: We have a form that is specified in an XML file. It consists of Button, TextViews, EditTexts, RadioButton  and Checkboxes. We parse the XML file and build up the UI with it. The Layout we have is a TableLayout with two columns. In the first column there is a text that describes the form field like "Your firstname". The second column has the actual form elements like EditTexts etc.

Comment: The code for adding the form elements to the layout is the mentioned few hundred lines of code. Basically it is not difficult to implement. Depending on how familiar you are with Java and Android it takes only a few hours to implement the Layout that is build up using XML.

Comment: So you have an array in your java class of type EditText, TextView, RadioButton etc, then just add as many as you require using loops? You see I have been tasked with being able to create a program which will allow customization of an Application from users by changing the XML. Just unsure of how to position each widget when I don't know in advance how many TextViews, EditTexts etc will be required. If I use a loop to declare them, how to position each individual one using parsed XML?

Comment: When I parse data, I have a class which contains Arraylists which stores all the parsed data. Do you store all your parsed data in ArrayList too?

I have couple of questions about code that I am not too sure about. FIrst, see the page.getChildren. What is that part about? Do you have a variable set up in the XmlElement Class? Also If I try to use params.setMargins, it comes up with an error. 

Only been doing android programming for month, and I have a lot to learn for my work, and I dont get any training in work, all has to be self taught. So sorry if questions seem a bit basic :P

Comment: An XML file has a tree-like structure. The XmlElement is also a tree which has the same structure as the XML file. `getChildren()` returns the child elements of an XML element - so basically an ArrayList of children. The XmlElement class has fields for any information that an XML element can have. What error do you get when you try using `params.setMargins`?